# Signal specific points in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Having a basic chart like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

... is there any way to create a little arrow, let's say, into the obs-points "3" and "5"? I have this need because I work with financial series and I would like to highlight with small arrows the points in which some events happened (according to a list of boolean occurrencies True/False). So, in the case I've asked above, the occurrency list would be `[False, False, True, False, True, False]` but I guess for this it's enough to multiply the vector by the original array so that I would get the markers at the right height.
[Here](http://www.mcoscillator.com/data/charts/weekly/Titanic2013.gif) is a more complex web example to give the visual idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: Browsing through the [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/gallery.html) is a good way to find examples for what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In matplotlib you can use text annotations to [annotate your graph suitably](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/annotations_intro.html). The code below shows a simple example where I have annotated the third point in your linear plot. Obviously if you were to do this in your own code you could provide a more intelligent way of picking x,y coordinations of the arrow point and the text.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

f, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(y, linestyle='None', marker='o')


for i in [2, 3, 4]:
    ax.annotate('', xy=(i-1, i), xytext=(i-1,i+0.5),
                arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black',
                                width=1,
                                shrink=0.1))

plt.margins(0.1)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT** I have modified the code to remove the text annotation to an empty string.

[image: Example plot]

Comment: That's useful, but in my case I would have a cloud of events'names that would make the chart unreadable. That's why I was looking for the basic simple arrows. Thanks though

Comment: I will edit my answer to show how you could gain the output you're after.

Comment: Yes please. But I'm getting the idea maybe, do you mean annotating an empty string and moving the text coordinates to get the original arrow vertically pointing down?

Comment: Alright, your solution seems nice but I fear two problems:
1) If I need to get the output arrow through all the True I have into my occurrencies list, this means I will need to iterate through the list and making a `ax.annotate()` call for every `True` I find in it?
2) In the case I have different occurrencies vectors (example: black arrows for the event 1, red arrows for the event 2 etc.) I guess I will need to code something to change the `arrowprops`... but like this I will have to predefine a certain set of colors (cause I never know in advance) [WILL CONTINUE IN NEXT COMMENT]

Comment: [CONTD](what is the number of occurrencies vectors the user wants to plot) and iterate through this as well?

Comment: In answer to 1) yes you'll have to iterate over your list I believe (I don't know how your data is set up so it's hard to say for sure). In answer to two you could have some boolean check in your iteration (such as `if some_thing == some_other_thing: arrow_color='red'`) which will check and then change the arrow color for you.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. Just the last question: is there anyway through the arrow properties to make it a bit more separated from the data point?

Comment: Yes change `shrink` to be a larger float, it controls how distanced the arrow is from the `xy` coordinate. You may also want to try [`plt.arrow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.arrow) if you know you're not going to need any text (an example can be [found here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/arrow_simple_demo.html).

Comment: I've played a bit around, this solution seems working in all cases and be very easy to implement so I've marked your answer. Thanks.